# Invalid identifier SQL creating a table with foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier

I'm learning SQL but I think this should work what is happening?

[image]

It's a simple table with a normal foreing key referenced table

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
FOREIGN KEY (DNI) REFERENCES RESIDENTES
```

you should have

```
FOREIGN KEY (your_column_name) REFERENCES RESIDENTES(DNI)
```

where `your_column_name` is the column in the table `RESERVA` 
that you want to reference the column `DNI` of the table `RESIDENTES`.

Answer (score 0):

Your table `RESERVA` does not have a column named `DNI`. How could it be a foreign key? Add the column `DNI` and problem solved.

The same can be said about `OID_SALA`.